# Using global dictionary for settings: good or bad convention

Tags: python

I'm writing comment to a function that gets settings from a json file, I found my [Github Copilot](https://github.com/features/copilot) suggesting it being not a good idea to do so. I've looked into [Why are global variables evil? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil/19158418#19158418) and see mixed opinion on "bad" or "evil" depending on the circumstances. In this case, is using global dictionary objects for settings a good call?

```py
# tools.py
def get_settings() -> dict:
    # Having empty global variable for settings is necessary to check if settings is loaded    global settings
    if 'settings' in globals():
        return settings

    if os.path.isfile('settings.json'):
        with open('settings.json', 'r') as f:
            settings = json.load(f)
            return json.load(f)
```

[image: COPILOT saying it's not a good idea]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem comes when you try to use the settings, and especially when you try to *test* code that uses the settings. Suddenly all the code is coupled together around this one variable. It gets even more inconvenient if you want to split the code into different modules.

It's generally more manageable, if slightly more verbose, to:

- keep the settings in a variable in main() and pass them where needed
- or use a dependency injection framework to provide them

(The DI framework will itself have globals, but provides more tools to manage them)